# How can I set up Sequelize.js to stream data instead of a promise / callback?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using `MySQL` and have a very large response (15,000+ rows). This takes.. well.. time. But I can start to process the first result right away. Can I set up a stream somehow with `sequelize`? If so, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a [related GitHub for this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2454). It doesn't look like it will happen in the near future.

For now I am monitoring my console, saving the query that Sequelize generates, and then refactoring my code to run the query with [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/).

```
connection.query(mySavedQuery).stream().pipe(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `node-sequelize-stream` library.

Comment: Apparently this module is running multiple queries with offset and limit [here](https://github.com/nkovalenko93/sequelize-stream/blob/d743f27a7622c49e5a737965ae79900456bc1424/index.js#L134). Streaming will be done in `O(n^2)` IO complexity.